# How to not count blank rows in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, count, countif

I have data in two columns B and C. B columns contain the date and C contains a value. The data starts from B2 to B569. However, I am only interested in the last 5 years data. So I have written a code that counts the number of rows and If the count is > 60 then it deletes the unwanted rows. Now If I a new value is added then I have given a condition to shift all rows up and delete the first value so that the total number of rows is always 60 which is the last 5 years data.
But when I run the code the first condition is always true why?. I think it is because the code is counting all the rows in the range B2 to B569 including the blank rows. Is there a way in which I can only count the data with values?

This is the code that I'm using

```
If Range("B2:B569").Rows.Count > 60 Then
 Range("B2:B509").Select
 Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
 
 Else
 If Range("B2:B569").Rows.Count = 61 Then
 Range("B2:C2").Select
 Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
 MsgBox "One New Index Value Found"
 
 Else
 If Range("B2:B569").Rows.Count = 60 Then
 MsgBox "Pass"
 
 Else
 
 MsgBox "Fail"

End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

if the last five years of data is only in column B and there is a mix of blank and non blank cells then its counting everything.

you need to set i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B2:B569")). Note this only counts non blank cells on that range. When it comes to identifying positions of non blank cells between blank cells. Instead of using a complex code, its probably better to filter the blanks, sort a to z and see which date exceeds 5 years. No macro needed